# What does "Norm" term mean?

Tags: neural-network

In [this paper (page 1 abstract)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.08400.pdf) which considers regularization technique, the author used the word "norm" - what does it stand for?
Is it related to Batch Normalization / L1 or L2 Normalization?

> "We stabilize the activations of Recurrent Neural Networks (RNNs) by penalizing
>   the squared distance between successive hidden states’ norms"

Googling "what is a norm Neural Net" doesn't provide any links

Comment: The state of a neural network is a vector or tensor, and these mathematical objects have [norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A norm is a concept in linear algebra which assigns a *size* to a vector. Many different norms exist you can read up on their many uses [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)).

In this paper, they are training a recurrent neural network. These are used for time series data. The assumption is a hidden state should be similar for successive time inputs $t$ and $t-1$. Thus, the author proposes an additional constraint based on the relative *size* of the successive hidden state vectors as

$||h_{t}||_2 - ||h_{t-1}||_2$.

The more different the norm of these successive states, the greater the cost will be.